# How can I pass build variables to VSTS through the VSTS CLI?

Tags: command-line-interface, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am trying to use the **VSTS-CLI** to kick off a build with different build variables. I have been able to kick off the build using this command:

```
 -/Users/ksg01/lib/vsts-cli/bin/vsts build queue --definition-name PointToPoint-nLightAir-Automation --open  --source-branch develop --instance xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx --project xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

These are [the build variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFblT.png) I am trying to update.

But I haven't been able to find a parameter for me to pass in the build variables. How can I do this? Or is there a resource that will help?

Comment: Okay so just an update in case anyone wants to do the same thing. I ended up sending VSTS REST API a POST request using Postman to accomplish this task. To take it to the next level I'm am currently looking into newman which is a CLI tool for Postman. Good luck!!

Comment: You can add the way to used in an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VSTS CLI does not have the ability to add parameters as far as I could tell. Using Postman's CLI tool Newman I was able to send a query to the VSTS REST API and queue a build.

Answer (score 1):

Although it does not appear to be documented in any of Microsoft's documentation if you ask for help from the command line (`vsts build queue -h`) it describes a `--variables` property that can be used to pass in space separated "name=value" pairs. I've successfully used it to pass an msbuild property to my build definition (`vsts build queue --definition-name mybuild --variables myvar=value`).

Environment info: vsts cli 0.1.1, Visual Studio 2017